# Creating DB issue, Visual Studio 2010

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio-2010

I joined a Windows Domain and I installed SQL Express, and I chose to use Windows authentication and SQL authentication as login methods, I forgot the sa, and I got back to WORKGROUP instead of the domain that I joined, trying to login or adding a sysadmin user was not possible, so I had to create a new SQLExpress Instance that I called SQLExpress2008, now I opened visual Studio 2010, and I'm trying to create a database, and It's failing telling me it cannot connect to the instance, is there a way to either restore that SQLExpress instance or set the default Visual Studio instance to SQLExpress2008 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this myself:

Tools > Options > Database Tools > Data Connections >

SQL Server Instance Name (blank for default)